# Google Calendar API list() limits

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I use [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and share the email address with a calendar. I listed all events of the calendar successfully using [API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list). The problem is after running the demo many times, the the list() API returns empty list. I've checked quotas but the remaining requests are still high (~900000 requests).

OK, I've tried to create another calendar and share the email address with it, then use the new calendarId. The result is list() API returns records successfully.

It seems that the list() API has a request limit. Does anybody have this problem? I wonder if it is an undocumented restriction.

If you have time, I will send you the TeamViewer ID.

Update: This is the main code that I get  from [Calendar API sample](http://goo.gl/FUmLjN)

```
Events feed = client.events().
        list(GoogleAppHelper.GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID).
        setTimeMin(getTimeMin(currentTime)).
        setTimeMax(getTimeMax(currentTime)).
        execute();
View.display(feed);
```

Comment: Quota limit is for entire API not for single method. However, each method which sends request to API consumes quota. Calendar API default limit is 1million QPD. Are you sending same number of requests to new calendar as you did for old calendar(which gave empty list)??

Comment: No, I didn't send enough requests to reach the million QPD. But in a short time, I did many requests insert() & list(). I've checked this morning; the old calendar is still locked (maybe); the new calendar still works.